# How to configure ssh to allow specifying a hostname/IP in DISPLAY variable?

Tags: ssh, x11, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I have an old application I'm trying to run on CentOS6 that uses a couple machines: abc1 and abc2.

I log into abc1 and run the application, which ssh's to abc2, changes the `DISPLAY` variable to `abc1:0.0` and runs a process that tries to open a new window on abc1. However, it fails with: `cannot open display`

If I just do an `ssh -X abc2` or `ssh -Y abc2`, I can open an xterm with no issue, but the DISPLAY variable is set to something like `localhost:10.0`

Note that abc1 resolves correctly (I can ping abc1 from abc2)

I cannot modify the application at all, so don't have control over the `DISPLAY` variable it's using. However, I can modify the configuration of both abc1 and abc2. I'm on an isolated network and do not care about security.

Is there something in ssh config or something else that I can change to allow `abc1:0.0` to work?

Comment: Is it the (unchangeable) application that modifies the DISPLAY variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are logging in locally to `abc1`, this might be irrelevant to you... but if you are using SSH X11 forwarding to connect from your workstation to `abc1`, then you could also start a *nested X server* on `abc1` to capture the incoming connection to `abc1:0.0` and pass it on to your workstation's local X server within the secure SSH X11 tunnel.

On RHEL/CentOS 6, the RPM packages needed for this are either `xorg-x11-xserver-Xnest` or `xorg-x11-xserver-Xephyr` (newer implementation, might perform better).

Basically:

- have the regular X server on `abc1` in its default state of not listening for TCP connections
- have a local X server running on your workstation
- establish a X11-forwarding SSH connection from your workstation to `abc1`
- start `Xnest` or `Xephyr` in the background on `abc1` with the proper options to make them listen on `abc1:0.0`
- start your application.

---

Referring to @roaima's comment on the question: even with old X applications, hardcoding the DISPLAY setting within the application would always have been an extremely obnoxious thing to do.

It is highly likely that the DISPLAY variable is instead set somewhere configurable. For example, it might be specified in the login script of the user account that is used to run the application. But if modifying that counts as modifying the application, then you'll have to use the suggested workarounds.

Comment: And depending on the situation, there are of course other variants, like hijacking the resolution of `abc1` with `/etc/hosts` or a DNS server and forwarding it to your required server, or using `Xvfb` if you just want the application to run and don't care about the windows, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Brief explanation of what happens:

X forwarding via `ssh` creates a local X-protocol socket on the remote machine (abc2), just like an X server on the remote machine would, and then forwards the X wire protocol via the ssh-tunnel to the original machine (abc1). The local socket is identified as `localhost:10.0`.

OTOH, a `abc1:0.0` display uses the old X networking protocol, and expects the X server on abc1 to be listening on the correct ports. This is disabled by default on modern systems, because it's very insecure.

So if your situation is that you indeed want the application running on abc2 to use the X server running on abc1, the simplest way is to start the X server on abc1 without the `-nolisten` option. For that you have to find out how the X server is started (usually by an display manager, e.g xdm/gdm/kdm/lightdm), and modify the startup call.

The next thing you have to do is to enable access control. On an isolated network, just use `xhost +` and allow all connections; otherwise you can use `xauth` and add the current MIT magic cookie. Details depend a bit on how exactly the X server is configured on your machines.

Comment: On the X servers of the newest Linux distributions, the sense of TCP listening options may be flipped the other way, so instead of **removing** the `-nolisten TCP` option you may have to **add** `-listen TCP`.